# Can I avoid being photographed in my office?

Tags: termination, privacy

Call me old-fashioned, but I'm one of those people who doesn't like to be photographed. I don't really have a reason, I just don't like it.

In my office, instead of having a timesheet, there is a "log in computer" where you're expected to log in and out each day. The computer also takes your photo. There is a notification saying your photo is being taken, but I don't like it. They say it's for "safety" reasons, but it's obviously to track when you come and leave work and to make sure it's actually you logging in.

There are obvious ways to get around having my photo taken (like standing aside, covering the camera, etc), but can I get fired if I do that?

FYI: I'm in Australia

Comment: Curious, in what kind of domain is that normal policy ? (I don't want specific company name here) Defense ? Aerospace ? Drugs ?

Comment: Is that an actual picture of you in the thumbnail?

Comment: *Just don't like it* won't cut it as a valid reason

Comment: @JustDoIt So if I follow you around taking photos and you say, "don't do that, I don't like it". I can say that won't cut it as a reason?

Comment: @Max construction

Comment: The context of the situation is different, you should be able to see that @Coomie you're not being harassed, you're just asked to follow policy

Answer (score 11):

I would not make an issue out of this. It's a company security protocol, I dislike my photo being taken as well, but I'm probably under several different security surveillance cameras every single day when I visit clients. To me there is not much difference really than a biometric scanner for logging in and logging out of work.

I'm not keen on having my fingerprint taken either, but it's the price I pay to work in some places, an airport is not going to change it's security protocols to comply with me. If I felt strongly enough about it, I could vote with my feet and leave. But I don't and neither should you.

Choose your battles wisely, and fight the ones which are actually winnable and will have a positive outcome for you. This one will not do anything positive for you.

Whether you would be fired over it is up to the company, I would think not, but it would come across as petty and unprofessional and might start people scrutinising you a bit closer to see if you are actually a suitable person to have around, and I would expect that you'd get a warning of some sort at best, or disciplinary action of some kind, and be ordered to comply.